# Loading XAML workflow with multiple activity assemblies

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a XAML workflow which, which uses custom activities that are stored in more than one dlls. I’m trying to execute this workflow using WorkflowApplication. However I cannot figure out how to resolve multiple reference assemblies, while loading the XAML. I’m aware that the XamlXmlReaderSettings provides a LocalAssembly property, which allows us to provide the reference assembly. However, it only allows to provide a single assembly. How do I provide multiple reference assemblies to the reader, so that it is able to resolve the external types? Any help will be greatly appreciated. I’ve pasted the code I’m using for reference.

```
public void LoadWorkflowFromFileAsync(string workflowXaml, Assembly activityAssembly)
{
   var xamlReaderSettings = new XamlXmlReaderSettings
   {
      LocalAssembly = activityAssembly
   };
   var xamlSettings = new ActivityXamlServicesSettings
   {
      CompileExpressions = true
   };
   using (var reader = new XamlXmlReader(workflowXaml, xamlReaderSettings))
   {
      _activity= ActivityXamlServices.Load(reader, xamlSettings);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your `xmlns` in the XAML include the assembly name (ex. `xmlns:ede="clr-namespace:Sample.MyActivityLibrary;assembly=Sample.MyActivityLibrary"`)?

I'm not aware of anyway to reference multiple local assemblies in XamlXmlReaderSettings but if the assembly is referenced in the XAML it should resolve automatically.

Comment: That's what I used to think. But then I tried it out, and looks like it is possible. Ultimately I had to hook onto the AppDomain AssemblyResolve event to load multiple assemblies.